# Getting a syntax error in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error and I don`t know why. Can you please help me out?
I am trying to read in multiple .csv files.

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

gas_prices= sorted(glob('Gas prices/2020****_EEXGasFutures_SettlementPrices.csv'))
gas_prices

pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file).assign(filename = file)
           for file in gas prices), ignore_index = True)
```

Error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-17-cacfa11dbcf0>", line 2
    for file in gas prices), ignore_index = True)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Change `for file in gas prices` to `for file in gas_prices` with underscore

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

Comment: the error states clearly, gas prices is wrong. use gas_prices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a syntactical error, in `pd.concat()` `gas prices` should be `gas_prices`:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

gas_prices= sorted(glob('Gas prices/2020****_EEXGasFutures_SettlementPrices.csv'))

pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file).assign(filename = file)
           for file in gas_prices), ignore_index = True)
```